# Is CordovaMapSample at netbean only work with android SDK 4.2

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

The latest Netbeans IDE 7.4 sample project CordovaMapSample build fails with error "Error: Please install Android target 17 (the Android 4.2 SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run `android` from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools."

i have install the latest android SDK which is 4.3 , and this error still appears, is this project only able to work with Android SD 4.2 or is that anyway to make it run with android sdk 4.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely related to Cordova and ability to build project on 4.3. See for instance similar problem

[Cordova-CLI & PhoneGap-CLI do not see android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708739/cordova-cli-phonegap-cli-do-not-see-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

you can controll this in AndroidManifest.xml file. You have to specify lowest version of Android that your app will support and the build version. I already responded with more detail on previous asked question. If you need I will send you a snapshot.